# .NET Standard 2.0 - Windows Registry - works on Mac OS X - Unity

Tags: windows, macos, unity-game-engine, registry, .net-standard-2.0

I have my project (originally developed on Unity - Windows) on API Compatibility Level set to .NET Standard 2.0, and in my project I have an external .dll class library compiled also as .NET Standard 2.0 in which is used Microsoft.Win32. I am saving some data to the Windows Registry.

Now I am adapting the project to work on Mac too, and I found that my external .dll with the Registry thing is working with no error on my Mac also.

I've been trying to find where could that data be stored, as Mac's OS X doesn't have a Windows like Registry?

Why and how is this working?

The code is used as a .dll plugin in Unity.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

...

```
    private RegistryKey key;

    public StorageImpl()
    {
        key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyPath, true);

        if (key == null)
        {
            key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(RegistryKeyPath);
        }
    }

    public DateTime? StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            object value = key.GetValue(RegistryStartDate);
            return value != null ? DateTime.FromBinary((long)value) : (DateTime?)null;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                key.SetValue(RegistryStartDate, value.Value.ToBinary(), RegistryValueKind.QWord);
            }
            else
            {
                key.DeleteValue(RegistryStartDate);
            }

            key.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you show us the relevant part of your code, we might be able to find out what the methods you use do on macOS.

Comment: @frankhermes I updated my post. It's a simple implementation of saving data to the Registry. Also I must point out again that the compiled .dll is used as a plugin in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the data is being saved:
*/Users/user/.mono/registry/CurrentUser/software/nameOfSoftware/values.xml*

I had to search manually listing all folder content using terminal: *ls -a*

Comment: Were you able to get this to build? I recently downloaded an open-source project that requires this Nuget package, but I can't get Nuget to download it.

Comment: I was. My procedure was to create a .NET Standard 2.0 class project in VS and there I got all the needed dependencies for that Standard. Afterwards I've built the project and put the resulting .dlls into Unity's Plugin folder.